# Stringify all values in a newline delimited JSON by keys

Tags: java, json, amazon-s3, delimiter

I have a newline delimited JSON and I wish to change values of type map to strings using Java. An example is:

```
{"id": 1, "data": {}}
{"id": 1, "data": {"time": 43}}
{"id": 1, "data": {"class" : {"students" : [{"name" : "Jane"}]}}}
```

should be changed to

```
{"id": 1, "data": "{}"}
{"id": 1, "data": "{\"time\": 43}"}
{"id": 1, "data": "{\"class\" : {\"students\" : [{\"name\" : \"Jane\"}]}}"}
```

I wish to stringify all the `data` map values. How can I do this?

Comment: Did you mean to escape the data in the quotes, or is it truly intended to be unescaped?

`"{"time": 43}"` => `"{\"time\": 43}"`?

Comment: Sorry about that, I have changed it to escape. Thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem that calls for a JSON processor, since this will provide for the most bullet-proof, simple solutions.  Java doesn't come with built-in JSON processing, so this will require a third party library.  One commonly used Java JSON library is [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson).

Since this particular request involves working with arbitrary data formats, the Jackson Tree Model in the [Jackson Databind](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind) library is a good fit.

```java
String delimitedJson = "{\"id\": 1, \"data\": {}}\n"
        + "{\"id\": 1, \"data\": {\"time\": 43}}\n"
        + "{\"id\": 1, \"data\": {\"class\" : {\"students\" : [{\"name\" : \"Jane\"}]}}}";

StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

JsonMapper jsonMapper = JsonMapper.builder().build();
MappingIterator<ObjectNode> i = 
        jsonMapper.readerFor(ObjectNode.class).readValues(delimitedJson);
i.forEachRemaining((ObjectNode jsonNode) -> 
        output.append(convertObjectsToString(jsonMapper, jsonNode).toString())
                .append("\n"));
System.out.println(output);

// ...

private ObjectNode convertObjectsToString(JsonMapper jsonMapper, 
                                          ObjectNode jsonNode) {
    ObjectNode copy = jsonMapper.createObjectNode();
    jsonNode.fields().forEachRemaining(e -> {
        if (e.getValue() instanceof ObjectNode) {
            copy.set(e.getKey(), new TextNode(e.getValue().toString()));
        } else {
            copy.set(e.getKey(), e.getValue());
        }
    });
    return copy;
}
```

### Explanation

The `ObjectMapper` class is the primary class in the Jackson Databind library, and `JsonMapper` is the JSON-format specific implementation.

After creating the instance (using `JsonMapper.builder().build()`), we iterate over each element of the newline-delimited list using [`ObjectReader.readValues(delimitedJson)`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.13/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectReader.html#readValues-java.lang.String-), which reads a number of whitespace separated JSON values from an input source.  In this example, I'm assuming the root level JSON values in your list are objects, and not e.g. strings or ints.

```java
MappingIterator<ObjectNode> i =
        jsonMapper.readerFor(ObjectNode.class).readValues(delimitedJson);
i.forEachRemaining((ObjectNode jsonNode) ->
        output.append(convertObjectsToString(jsonMapper, jsonNode).toString())
                .append("\n"));
```

The custom `convertObjectsToString` method returns an `ObjectNode`, which is converted to JSON using [`toString()`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.13/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/node/BaseJsonNode.html#toString--).

The `convertObjectsToString` method starts by creating a new empty `ObjectNode`.  For each property in the source node, if it's not a JSON object type, it is copied over directly.  If it is a JSON object, it is converted to the JSON string representation of the object.

```java
private ObjectNode convertObjectsToString(JsonMapper jsonMapper, 
                                          ObjectNode jsonNode) {
    ObjectNode copy = jsonMapper.createObjectNode();
    jsonNode.fields().forEachRemaining(e -> {
        if (e.getValue() instanceof ObjectNode) {
            copy.set(e.getKey(), new TextNode(e.getValue().toString()));
        } else {
            copy.set(e.getKey(), e.getValue());
        }
    });
    return copy;
}
```